# Get an item from a list if its index is on another list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Well, I was looking on the site and I didn't find anything that could help me, so I came to ask. How do I get **items** from a **list** if its **index** is on another **list**?

Example:

I have an array of vectors:

`[[0.0,0.0,0.1] [0.4,0.23,0.175] [0.0,1.,0.5] [0.0,0.03,0.1] [0.02,0.0,0.3]]`

and a list of indices:

`[0,2,3]`

I want a result like this:

`[[0.0,0.0,0.1] [0.0,1.,0.5] [0.0,0.03,0.1]]`

how can I get this result? Grateful for any help :)

Comment: Can you show your effort?

Comment: sigh... your question answers itself. you have the indices already. just select based on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension.

For example:

```
mylist = [[0.0,0.0,0.1], [0.4,0.23,0.175], [0.0,1.,0.5], [0.0,0.03,0.1], [0.02,0.0,0.3]]
indices = [0,2,3]
result = [mylist[i] for i in indices]
```

result is now `[[0.0, 0.0, 0.1], [0.0, 1.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.03, 0.1]]`

Comment: You should not name a list as ```input```. Name it ```Input``` or anything else

Comment: Fair enough, I renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
lst1 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.1], [0.4, 0.23, 0.175], [0.0, 1., 0.5], [0.0, 0.03, 0.1], [0.02, 0.0, 0.3]]
lst2 = [0, 2, 3]
lst3 = [x for idx, x in enumerate(lst1) if idx in lst2]
print(lst3)
```

output

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.1], [0.0, 1.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.03, 0.1]]
```